# Entity Framework App Service: Adding B2C Auth fails with: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme foun

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to set up auth for my middleware with azure ad b2c. I am able to get a token from my ios client. I am now trying to config my middleware to allow this token onto the db.

But I am having issues with this line of code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureADB2C"));
```

If I swap the JwTBearerDefaults with OpenIdConnectDefaults
the middleware starts and immeadiately redirects me from:

https://skillbasedmiddleware.azurewebsites.net/tables/useritems?ZUMO-API-VERSION=3.0.0

to the native client
(but it remains empty - not sure if this is expected).

But if I use the JwTBearerDefaults (which I think I must as I auth user with a jwt token)
the app fails with:

[image]

Here is my full code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection1");

if (connectionString == null)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("DefaultConnection is not set");
}


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureADB2C"));
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to 
    // the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Index");
})
.AddMvcOptions(options => { });

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MigrationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatasyncControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Initialize the database
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MigrationDbContext>();
    //await context.InitializeDatabaseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

app.UseRouting();


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

and the config:

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://skillbasedauth.b2clogin.com",
    "ClientId": "asd",
    "Domain": "skillbasedauth.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-oidc",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_NewUser"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```